# Large number of VHDL signal assignments... can this be condensed?

Tags: vhdl

Within an architecture I have a large number of concurrent signal assignments that follow a specific formula, in this case:

```
x(i) <= x(i-1) XOR x(i-4) XOR ROTATE_LEFT(x(i-8), 2)
```

Example:

```
architecture behavioural of blah is
    --Signals
    type sigArrayType is array(127 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);  
    signal sigArray : sigArrayType  :=  ((others => (others => '0')));
begin

    sigArray(8) <= sigArray(7) XOR sigArray(4) XOR (ROTATE_LFET(sigArray(0), 2);
    sigArray(9) <= sigArray(8) XOR sigArray(5) XOR (ROTATE_LFET(sigArray(1), 2);
    sigArray(10) <= sigArray(9) XOR sigArray(6) XOR (ROTATE_LFET(sigArray(2), 2);
    --...
    --...
    --LOTS OF OTHER ASSIGNMENTS
    --...
    --...
    sigArray(127) <= sigArray(126) XOR sigArray(123) XOR (ROTATE_LFET(sigArray(119), 2);
end behavioural;
```

Is there a way to have VHDL automatically do this, rather than making me type out over a hundred versions?
Am I just looking for a simple "FOR" statement or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VHDL has a `generate` construction with loop (`for`) for this purpose, so you can write the code as:

```
x_gen : for i in 8 to 127 generate
  x(i) <= x(i-1) XOR x(i-4) XOR ROTATE_LEFT(sigArray(i-8), 2);
end generate;
```

VHDL also has an conditional generate (`if`).  You can try to [google VHDL generate statement](http://www.google.com/#q=vhdl+generate+statement), of may be look at [generate statement](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00033.htm).  Note that VHDL-2008 has enhanced the `generate` statement.

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew it would be simple. From the documentation I'd seen, it looked to me like the "generate" statement was used for creating components, but perhaps that's just another use.

Comment: The generate statement is for making repeated and conditional concurrent statements.  The book "[The Designer's Guide to VHDL - 3rd edition](http://www.amazon.com/s?search-alias=stripbooks&field-isbn=0120887851)" has a chapter "Generate Statements" about that.